# SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused when trying to Dockerize Laravel App

Tags: php, mysql, docker-compose, dockerfile, laravel-8

I was able to access the **mysql database** from **phpmyadmin** using **user: admin** and **password: root** and the **url: 127.0.0.1:3310** and I was able to load the website on **127.0.0.1:8008** but when i try to login or interact with the database i get the error below:

> SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused
> select * from `users` where `email` = boyiajas@gmail.com limit 1

and I also try to do a **migration** from within the **app docker container** but failed as well

```
root@58a709f18668:/var/www/html# php artisan migrate

   Illuminate\Database\QueryException 

  SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused (SQL: select * from information_schema.tables where table_schema = laravelvueblog_db and table_name = migrations and table_type = 'BASE TABLE')
```

below is my **.env** file

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=db
DB_PORT=3309
DB_DATABASE=laravelvueblog_db
DB_USERNAME=admin
DB_PASSWORD=root
```

below is my **vhost.conf** file

```
<VirtualHost *:8008>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/public

    <Directory "/var/www/html/public">
        AllowOverride all
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

    #ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    #CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

below is my **Docker file**

```
FROM php:8-apache

USER root
RUN apt-get update -y && apt-get install -y openssl curl zip unzip git nano
RUN apt-get clean && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
RUN docker-php-ext-install mysqli pdo pdo_mysql opcache
RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer

WORKDIR /app
COPY . /app
COPY vhost.conf /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf

RUN chown -R www-data:www-data /app && a2enmod rewrite
RUN rm -rf /var/www/html && ln -s /app /var/www/html
RUN composer install
RUN php artisan optimize:clear

CMD php artisan serve --host=0.0.0.0 --port=8000
EXPOSE 8000
```

below is my **docker-compose.yaml file**

```
version: '3.8'
services: 
    db:
        image: mariadb:latest
        container_name: db
        ports:
            - 3309:3306
        environment:
            MYSQL_DATABASE: laravelvueblog_db
            MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
            MYSQL_PASSWORD: root
            MYSQL_USER: admin            
        volumes:
            - mysql_file:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
        networks:
            - appnetwork
    main:
        build: 
            context: .
            dockerfile: Dockerfile
        volumes:
            - .:/app
        ports:
            - 8008:8000
        environment:
            # MYSQL_DATABASE: laravelvueblog_db
            # MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
            # MYSQL_PASSWORD: root
            # MYSQL_USER: admin
            DB_HOST: db
            DB_USER: admin
            DB_PASSWORD: root
            DB_NAME: laravelvueblog_db
            WAIT_HOSTS: db:3306

        depends_on:
            - db
        links:
            - db
        networks:
            - appnetwork

    phpmyadmin:
        image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
        ports:
            - 3310:80
         links:
            - mysql
        environment:
            PMA_HOSTS: db
            PMA_PORT: 3306
        depends_on:
            - db
        networks:
            - appnetwork
 volumes:
     mysql_file:
         driver: local
 networks:
     appnetwork:
         driver: bridge
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After several attempt I found the problem, since all the services are on the same network (**appnework**)

I used the internal port in my laravel .env file like below

```
DB_PORT=3306
```

And now it works fine